# Can we filter sharepoint document library list view by applying the filter parameters to the URL AllItems.aspx

Tags: 2013, development, document-library, list-view

I am working on a sharepoint enterprise farm 2013. and i have a document library with the defualt built-in list view which can be accessed using this url `http://servername/sitename/listname/Forms/AllItems.aspx`. now inside the document library i have defined some custom site columns, as follow:-

1. document type. of type drop-down
2. document description. of type multiple line of text.
3. etc...

now my question is if i can filter the list view by applying the filter parameters to the list view url. so if i want the documents which have type= "General", can i do something as follow:-

`http://servername/sitename/listname/Forms/AllItems.aspx?documenttype=general`

now i tried this, but it will return the list view with all the documents, so seems it ignored this part `?documenttype=general`.. so my question is can i have the ability to apply filter parameters to the list view url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can in a different format as below

```
http://servername/sitename/Lists/ListName/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=DocumentType&FilterValue1=General
```

Similarly if you want to add more criteria just add `&FitlerField2=...`

Comment: Your format is wrong.. try the one I provided..

Comment: now i tried your format, but i got this error "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.

"

Comment: Make sure the field name DocumentType is the proper name

Comment: now inside the list view page i use to have content editor web part, now when i remove it i can filter the list correctly...

Comment: Make the content editor Webpart the second Webpart of the page

Comment: ok now i got this partially working.. as when i type this filter inside the URL `FilterField1=DocumentType&FilterValue1=General` i got all the documents which are directly added to the document library + have their documenttype=general... but for the documents which are added inside folders and their `documenttype=general`, they are not going to be shown after running the URL `http://servername/sitename/Lists/ListName/Forms/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=DocumentType&FilterValue1=General` .. is there a way to fix this? to have my filter work on documents inside folders?

Comment: Change the View settings to display all files without folder

Comment: i did not get your point.. now we have organized our documents inside folders.. so i do not want to change it... now what i am trying to do is to build a search for my document library, and i want to benefit from the `FilterField1=Docum‌​entType&FilterValue1‌​=General` appraoch to be showing the search results based on the users search criteria... did u get my point ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `QueryString Filter web part` to filter the current view based on the query string parameter!

[image]

The syntax for Query string parameter

```
http://servername/sitename/listname/Forms/AllItems.aspx?<Name>=<Val>
```

For multiple Query string parameters

```
http://servername/sitename/listname/Forms/AllItems.aspx?<Name>=<Val>&<Name>=<Val>
```

**Check the details at**

- [Connect a Query String (URL) Filter Web Part to another Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-a-Query-String-URL-Filter-Web-Part-to-another-Web-Part-8fd0107f-4889-451b-a7f7-d1996e12a8d1)
- [Query string (URL) filter](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/10/28/open-filter-list-url-modal-dialog-sharepoint/)

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. now i tried this query `http://servername/sitename/listname/Forms/AllItems.aspx?<Name>=<Val>&<Name>=<Val>` where i was able to filter the list view accordingly. but if i have documents inside folders then seems the list view filter will not show the documents which are added inside the folders.. for example i type this url `http://servername/sitename/Lists/ListName/Forms/AllItems.asp‌​x?FilterField1=Docum‌​entType&FilterValue1‌​=General`

Comment: where i get all the documents which are added directly to the document library and have their document type= general.. but for the documents which were added inside folders they are not going to be shown, even if their document type = general.. so do you have any idea if i can fix this problem ?

Comment: I got your point, you need to get the documents inside folders that match the filter criteria! unfortunately, the filter criteria don't apply to the documents inside the folder! it's not working like the search it just a filter! and the available solution is to modify your view to show all files but I think this does not match your requirements!